# Pandas Make Some Last Column Values Zero

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the form:

```
id -> t1 t2 t3 t4 ... t1000
```

where t1...t1000 are columns with float values.

I want to do:

For every id,

randomly set a few number of the last columns zero.

e.g. for each id:

set columns t_random_number to t1000 to zero values.

Comment: How many you want to set as zero ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen i want to set a radom number of them to zero for each id.. random number oculd be any number between 1 and 10.

Comment: @WeNYoBen any hints on how to do that? much appreciated

Comment: You only want the random number (RN) between 1 and 10? So you would set columns RN - t1000 for each row (indexed by `id`)?